# Using Kendo Grid with Server Side Filters and Server Side Sorting, Field = NULL?

Tags: javascript, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using A Kendo Grid, With Server Side Filtering and Server Side Sorting. In my Data Source Transport Read method the field is always null. Any Suggestions?

This my code for initializing the Grid:

```
var gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("Read", "GridModule")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json'
                },
                parameterMap: function (options) {
                    options.assignmentFilters = assignmentFilters;
                    return JSON.stringify(options);
                }
            },
            pageSize: 20,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverSorting: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        LastSurveyDate: { type: "date" },
                        LastNoteDate: { type: "date" }
                    }
                },
                data: "data",
                total: "totalRows"
            }
        });

        var $grid = $('#gridAssignments');

        if (e.firstLoad) {
            $grid.kendoGrid({
                scrollable: true,

                pageable: {
                    refresh: true,
                    pageSizes: [20, 50, 100, 500, 1000],
                    buttonCount: 12,
                    messages: {
                        display: "Showing {0}-{1} from {2} Provider Contacts",
                        empty: "No Contacts Match the Filter Criteria",
                        itemsPerPage: "Contacts per page"
                    }
                },
                reorderable: true,
                navigatable: true,
                change: gridOnChange,
                dataBound: gridOnDataBound,
                dataSource: gridDataSource,
                columnReorder: gridColumnReorder, 
                columnHide: gridColumnHide,
                columnResize: gridColumnResize,
                columnShow: gridColumnShow,
                columnMenu: {
                    sortable: false,
                    messages: {
                        columns: "Choose columns",
                        filter: "Filter",
                       }
                },
                resizable: true,
                height: '720px',
                filterable: {
                    extra: false,
                    operators: {
                        string: {
                            contains: "Contains",
                        },
                        date: {
                            lt: "Is before", 
                            gt: "Is after",
                            equal: "On"
                        }
                    }
                },
                selectable: "row",
                sortable: {
                    mode: "single",
                    allowUnsort: true
                },
                columns: [ @Html.Raw(Model.GridColumns.Columns) ]
        });
        } else {
            $grid.data('kendoGrid').setDataSource(gridDataSource);
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean the Read method of GridModule is always getting null from client side? If I'm not mistaken you must also pass in the type to the parameter map function delegate like so: parameterMap: function(options, type) {}. Perhaps it's not hitting your function since you missing the arg.

Comment: Yes you are correct. In my read method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone that runs into the same problem...

In my case my code worked fine until I added two fields to the Schema.Model.Fields. Then for some reason the Field in my read method of my Grid Module was NULL. By default it all fields were treated as strings but when I added the two new properties then No default was used.

I had to add all my Grid's fields

```
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        LastSurveyDate: { type: "date" },
                        LastNoteDate: { type: "date" },
                        FirstName: { type: "string" },
                        LastName: { type: "string" },
                        HasNewEval: { },
                        HasCommitmentsToGet: { },
                        OnPriorityList: { type: "string" },
                        HasProductsBelowMinimum: { type: "HasProductsBelowMinimum" },
                        Points: {},
                        Title: { type: "string" },
                        Provider: { type: "string" },
                        Phone: { type: "string" },
                        TimeZone: { type: "string" },
                        Touches: { type: "string" },
                        LastNoteText: { type: "string" },
                        VerbalAging: { type: "string" }
                    }
                },
```

That worked for me.

Comment: Can you give me any clue how you handled server side for filtering?

Comment: Perfect. That was exactly my problem. It does not even seem that applying a "type" is necessary, only that the field be present in the schema->model->fields (if such is provided, it works fine automatically if no fields are provided).